# Is it possible to clear close votes or revert a migration?

Tags: feature-request, migration, vote-to-close, voting, moderator-tools

Recently [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6002203) was erroneously voted for close to be migrated to webmasters.stackexchange.com although it does belong to Stack Overflow.

There were already 4 close votes when I wished there was a moderator function to clear the close votes and seconds later the question was already migrated to Pro Webmasters. I asked the moderators to re-migrate it back to Stack Overflow and they did it promptly. But as [Sourav](https://stackoverflow.com/users/683233/sourav) has no account at Pro Webmasters, the question was re-migrated back to an anonymous user.

As a workaround I merged the re-migrated question with the original question to merge the new answers and to re-associate the question with Sourav.

This all seems to be a little complicated and I hope there is or will be a simpler solution to this kind of problems. Either an additional function to clear close votes or to get a migrated question back.

Comment: The last vote cast by a moderator is binding and overrides any previous close-vote reasons, even if they were in the majority. You could have simply voted to close as "off-topic", and then re-opened it. (At least, assuming you were fast enough before that 5th vote was cast. But the ability to clear close votes assumes that as well.)

Comment: Both posts are locked. I can't upvote either of them. I'm not sure I could answer them too. (Haven't had time to put an answer in)

Comment: @Cody - it might be better to choose something other than "off topic" as that adds a -1 vote to the question which doesn't appear to be removed when the question is reopened.

Comment: @Chris: Indeed. I'd forgotten about that little detail, not actually being a moderator myself and all... :-)

Comment: you're always welcome to drop by the Teachers Lounge to discuss this sort of thing with the mods on the other site.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't get there in time to override the migrate vote (as per Cody's comment) there are two scenarios:

1. No new answers on the target site.

   In this case the moderators on the two sites need to coordinate their actions (albeit loosely). A moderator on the original site can clear the migration history - this makes it look like the question was never migrated. A moderator on the target site can then simply delete their version of the question.
2. There are new answers on the target site.

   In this case the question really has to be re-migrated back to the original site and then merged with the first version in order to preserve all the answers.

If the post hasn't yet been migrated the simplest solution is to do as Cody suggests in his comment - choose another close reason (not "off topic" or "not a real question" as these will give a -1 vote to the question) and then reopen it.