# Could we have a "clear close votes to prevent migration" feature/option in the mod tools?

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools

This is related [to this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91254/is-it-possible-to-clear-close-votes-or-revert-a-migration). There have been quite a few times now where a question has been on the verge of being migrated to the wrong site. This one for example:

> [Apache mod_rewrite/mod_proxy - re-write last part of URI as query string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6501165/apache-mod-rewrite-mod-proxy-re-write-last-part-of-uri-as-query-string)

According to this Web Masters meta question, the accepted answer by one of their moderators says that they will accept "Why?" questions but not "How?" questions:

> [The mod_rewrite problem](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/328/the-mod-rewrite-problem)

The question as it stands is a "How?" question and valid on Stack Overflow, although it could also be valid on Server Fault:

> [Apache configuration/.htaccess questions (esp. mod_rewrite): SO or SF?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6235/apache-configuration-htaccess-questions-esp-mod-rewrite-so-or-sf)

Jeff's answer to this question provides us with some guidance:

> I'd also suggest that if your job
>   title contains the word "programmer",
>   go with Stack Overflow, and if your
>   job title does not, then go with
>   Server Fault.

To prevent this question being migrated I (rightly or wrongly) closed the question as just "Off Topic", re-opened then upvoted it to compensate for the close downvote it attracted.

It would be useful to have a way of pulling questions that are about to be migrated to what is clearly the wrong place back from the brink if they actually do belong where they presently are.

I guess I could have allowed the migration to happen then cleared the migration history, but that involves liaising with the destination site mods (to have the post deleted on their side) which for certain sites isn't particularly convenient.

Comment: I thought the close downvote got retracted if the question was reopened, but I could be wrong on that.

Comment: @anna - I'm sure it didn't which is why I upvoted as a compensation. I could also be wrong :)

Comment: @AnnaLear - from what I've seen it doesn't

Comment: @AnnaLear [Revert the Community downvote on a closed question when it gets reopened](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91211/revert-the-community-downvote-on-a-closed-question-when-it-gets-reopened) is a feature request, so it seems that the automatic downvote not retracted at the moment.

Comment: The close downvote does get retracted now @AnnaLear